# Bootstrap 4 columns not aligning as expected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am new to Bootstrap 4 but I have read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width) documentation and it seemed pretty straight forward, however I cannot get these columns to work. I am basically just trying to have all of the ads displayed on the left side of the page, taking up majority with `col-8`, and on the right side I'm just trying to setup a little box with a create post button in it. It will only take up `col-4` of the page.

Here's my HTML (NOTE: I'm using Django):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

This is the create a post page

{% block head %}
<!-- {% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'accounts/login.css' %}" type="text/css"> -->
<title>Zaneroo - Latest Ads</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container"><br>

<a href="{% url 'classifieds:create_post' %}">Post an Ad</a><br><br>

<section id="latest-ads">

  <div class="ads">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
        Ads
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <aside class="create-post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        Sidebar
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>

</section>



  {% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
  <br>{{ message }}<br>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

  {% for post in posts %}

  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I know that bootstrap is being picked up because the nav bar still works, the fonts aren't default and neither are the links but for some reason the columns aren't side by side. Just directly on top of each other.

In my base.html file where I am inheriting the nav I am using this version on bootstrap:

```
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

[Here](https://i.gyazo.com/05834ee94ff90d740d8c00c1826b9d16.png) is a picture of the HTML page in the browser.

Any help is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your columns are nested inside divs. Could be the problem.

Comment: I removed the outer divs and unfortunately that did not fix it. Thanks though.

Comment: Let me post an answer for you to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it within a container (or container-fluid), followed by a row, followed by your col's. For example

```
<section class="container" id="latest-ads">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 ads">
       Ads
    </div>
    <aside class="col-4 create-post">
     Sidebar
    </aside>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That fixed it, and your code also made me realize the initial error which was that I had two rows which is why the elements were displaying on top of each-other. Thank you. Picked as best.